# Search for series of ordered tokens in sentences represented as a dataframe of individual tokens

Tags: r, nlp, spacy, stringr

I am trying to learn more about corpus, word analysis in R. Recently I've started using CleanNLP and Spacy Backend. The question is, after parsing the text I would like to see if a sentence has the tokens tagged with different relations.

Let's say,

```
library(cleanNLP)
library(tidyverse)
text <- cnlp_annotate(c("I gave him money"))
```

Result would be

```
 doc_id   sid   tid token token_with_ws lemma  upos  xpos  tid_source relation
   <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>         <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <int> <chr>   
1      1     1     1 I     "I "          -PRON- PRON  PRP            2 nsubj   
2      1     1     2 gave  "gave "       give   VERB  VBD            0 root    
3      1     1     3 money "money "      money  NOUN  NN             2 dobj    
4      1     1     4 to    "to "         to     ADP   IN             2 dative  
5      1     1     5 him   "him"         -PRON- PRON  PRP            4 pobj
```

I mutated the dataframe via

```
dative <- c("dative")
     anno %>%
+     filter(grepl(dative, relation)) %>% 
+     select(sid, sentence)
```

and looked for before and after context

```
anno %>%
+     mutate(kwic = ifelse(grepl(dative, relation),
+                          TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
+     mutate(before = gsub("NA\\s?", "", paste(lag(token, 3), lag(token, 2), lag(token))),
+            after = gsub("NA\\s?", "", paste(lead(token), lead(token, 2), lead(token, 3)))
+     ) %>%
+     filter(kwic) %>%
+     select(before, token, after)
```

I would like to extract sentences from corpus which have all three relation tags (`dobj, dative, pobj`). I other words, I would like to check before and after context and extract sentences if before and after context has the tags `"dobj"` and `"pobj"`.

So basically, I would like to extract sentences with the pattern Dobj, Dative, Pobj (sentences with double objects; I gave money to him) but not with the pattern of one or two of the variables, let's say Dobj only; I gave the money or Preposition + Pobj; I gave to him.

How can I do this? Any help highly appreciated

So far, with the big help from @GeoffreyPoole, I have managed to get the list. with some edits of the code below, output is;

```
target <- "root dobj dative pobj"
text %>%
  select(sid, relation, lemma) %>%
  
  # get rid of any sentences with less than three words...
  group_by(sid) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n >= 4) %>%
  left_join(text) %>%
  
  # make sure tokens are in order...
  arrange(sid, tid, lemma) %>%
  
  # now, for each sentence...
  group_by(sid) %>%
  group_modify(
    function(x,y,z) {
      #paste together each triplet of relations and convert to a dataframe.
      rollapply(x[,c("relation", "token")], 4, paste, collapse = " ") %>%
                              as.data.frame
    }
  ) %>% 
  
  # get all unique combinations of sid and pasted triplets
  distinct %>%
  
  # select records with the desired pasted triplet
  filter(relation == target) %>%
  
  # and pull all of the tokens for associated sentences from text
  left_join(text)

sid relation              token                             doc_id   tid token_with_ws lemma upos  xpos  tid_source
   <int> <chr>                 <chr>                              <int> <int> <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr>      <int>
 1   949 root dobj dative pobj gives ideas to people                 NA    NA NA            NA    NA    NA            NA
 2  1242 root dobj dative pobj provided advantages for customers     NA    NA NA            NA    NA    NA            NA
 3  1631 root dobj dative pobj give harm to themselves               NA    NA NA            NA    NA    NA            NA
 4  2275 root dobj dative pobj say this to us                        NA    NA NA            NA    NA    NA            NA
 5  3016 root dobj dative pobj write fine to you                     NA    NA NA            NA    NA    NA            NA
 6  3826 root dobj dative pobj cause problem for society             NA    NA NA            NA    NA    NA            NA
 7  4184 root dobj dative pobj gives harm to women                   NA    NA NA            NA    NA    NA            NA
```

Only one question remains, do I need to edit `target` to see further relations? For instance when `target <- "root dobj dative pobj"`,
the results is

```
1242 root dobj dative pobj provided advantages for customers
```

What would happed if the actual sentece was

> "provided advantages for `the` customers"

do I need to re-write `target` as  `"root dobj dative (det) pobj"` to observed these patterns?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you provided a negative test as well so that solutions can be verified and we can make sure we are only returning what you want

Comment: Maybe just provide the value of `dput(text)` so the installation of cleanNLP/spacy isn't necessary to test possible solutions. This seems to be just a data filtering question rather than anything specific to cleanNLP.

Comment: Well,yes it is exactly a data filtering question. Can you please clarify "negative test" ? I am not sure if I got it.

Comment: A negative test would be a sentence it shouldn't match. Maybe a sentence that just has two out of the three.

Comment: I see, I would just edit my text right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revised question posed by @Fatih made me realize there is a much more robust (and efficient) answer to this question than I had originally posted.

The key is to make "sentences" out of the parts-of-speech rather than out of the tokens (words) themselves.  Then use `regex` (e.g., `grepl()`) to find the "sentences" with the desired patterns.

Here are some test data:

```
> text
# A tibble: 16 x 4
     sid   tid token     upos 
   <int> <int> <chr>     <chr>
 1     1     1 When      ADV  
 2     1     2 you       PRON 
 3     1     3 ’re       VERB 
 4     1     4 traveling VERB 
 5     2     1 You       PRON 
 6     2     2 also      ADV  
 7     2     3 see       VERB 
 8     2     4 a         DET  
 9     3     1 These     DET  
10     3     2 strings   NOUN 
11     3     3 of        ADP  
12     3     4 beads     NOUN 
13     4     1 They      PRON 
14     4     2 have      AUX  
15     4     3 been      AUX  
16     4     4 used      VERB
```

Let's say we want to find sentences with the pattern either "ADV VERB" or "ADV PRON VERB".  The regular expression would look like this:

```
regex = "ADV (PRON )?VERB"
```

So let's build some "sentences" out of parts of speech:

```
library(dplyr)

posSentences = 
  text %>%
  arrange(sid, tid) %>%
  group_by(sid) %>%
  summarize(uposSentence = paste(upos, collapse = " "))
```

The "sentences" look like this:

```
> posSentences
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    sid uposSentence      
  <int> <chr>             
1     1 ADV PRON VERB VERB
2     2 PRON ADV VERB DET 
3     3 DET NOUN ADP NOUN 
4     4 PRON AUX AUX VERB
```

You can see the first two sentences have our desired pattern.  The second two do not.  Now just use `grepl` to find the ones that conform with the regular expression:

```
theAnswer = filter(posSentences, grepl(regex, posSentences$uposSentence))
```

And we're done:

```
> theAnswer
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    sid uposSentence      
  <int> <chr>             
1     1 ADV PRON VERB VERB
2     2 PRON ADV VERB DET
```

You can get back to the tokens in these sentences with something like:

```
filter(text, sid %in% theAnswer$sid)
```

which yields, in this case:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
    sid   tid token     upos 
  <int> <int> <chr>     <chr>
1     1     1 When      ADV  
2     1     2 you       PRON 
3     1     3 ’re       VERB 
4     1     4 traveling VERB 
5     2     1 You       PRON 
6     2     2 also      ADV  
7     2     3 see       VERB 
8     2     4 a         DET
```

The above approach is substantially faster and more flexible than what I had offered when @Fatih's question was narrower (look for a specific pattern of three parts of speech).  So my former answer is moot, but I've left it below in case it is useful to anyone.

---

Original answer (for specific pattern of 3 values)

---

Here is a solution using `dplyr::group_modify` and `zoo::rollapply`.  Basically, by wrapping `rollapply` inside `group_modify`, you can `rollapply` across each sentence, and `paste` each triplet of relations together into a single string.  Then, simply `filter` for the desired `target` string.  You may or may not want to remove all of the punctuation tokens from `text` before running this code, depending on your objective.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

target = "dobj dative pobj"

text %>%
  select(sid, relation) %>%

  # get rid of any sentences with less than three words...
  group_by(sid) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n >= 3) %>%
  left_join(text) %>%

  # make sure tokens are in order...
  arrange(sid, tid) %>%

  # now, for each sentence...
  group_by(sid) %>%
  group_modify(
    function(x,y) {
      #paste together each triplet of relations and convert to a dataframe.
      rollapply(x[,"relation"], 3, paste, collapse = " ") %>%
        as.data.frame
    }
  ) %>% 

  # get all unique combinations of sid and pasted triplets
  distinct %>%

  # select records with the desired pasted triplet
  filter(relation == target) %>%

  # and pull all of the tokens for associated sentences from text
  left_join(text)
```

Comment: Awesome! Such an excellent way. I can now improve your code to handle even more data. Thank you very much. I really apperciate your help.

Comment: I got the output as a tible where sid and relation info stated, Is it possible to add lemma and sentence data to table? like `dobj - dative - pobj == give money to him == I gave money to him`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want.  Perhaps edit your original question to give an example of your desired output?

Comment: I solved out the problems I asked in the previous comment. Yet now I have one final question. I edited the original post.

Comment: Could use `toString` in `rollapply` as an alternative to `paste` with `collpase=`